# OpenCV behavior differences between Linux and Windows built application

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, g++, mingw-w64

I have an application that I wrote and tested in Windows that uses OpenCV for image evaluation.  It uses OpenCV 3.1.0 and was compiled with MinGW-W64 5.3.0.

Now, I've cloned this application and built and tested it in a Linux environment.  I did it on a Raspberry Pi first (Raspian Jessie) and then I did it on my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04, g++ 5.4.0).  I evaluated the same images and got different results.

There's too much code for me to post and expect everyone to sort through, so my basic question is, is there something I should specifically look for?  Right now I am debugging it on my laptop in Ubuntu, but if somebody had similar experience in the past and knew something to look for immediately it could save me some time.

### Thanks

I should mention what functions I'm using:

```
cv::cvtColor
cv::Blur
cv::Canny
cv::FindContours
cv::fitLine
cv::fitEllipse
```

Answer (score 5):

Image loading could be the one of the case. Please try to match the pixel values in windows & linux or mac after `imread`. Based on different version & codecs installed on machine it can vary little. This pixel values mis-match can happen for compressed image format like jpg, png, tiff etc. It should not happen for uncompressed format like pgm, bmp or in raw format. Please read the following lines from opencv documentation:

*1/ The function determines the type of an image by the content, not by      the file extension.*

*2/ On Microsoft Windows OS and MacOSX, the codecs    shipped with an OpenCV image (libjpeg, libpng, libtiff, and    libjasper) are    used by default. So, OpenCV can always read JPEGs, PNGs, and    TIFFs. On MacOSX, there is also an option to use native MacOSX    image readers. But beware that currently these native image       loaders give images with different pixel values because of the color     management embedded into MacOSX.*

*3/ On Linux, BSD flavors and other    Unix-like open-source    operating systems, OpenCV looks for codecs    supplied with an OS    image. Install the relevant packages (do not    forget the    development files, for example, “libjpeg-dev”, in Debian and    Ubuntu) to get the codec support or turn on the       OPENCV_BUILD_3RDPARTY_LIBS flag in CMake.*

[Link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread)

Comment: Thubsup. There is a difference in the same bitmaps saved as PNG under windows compared with Linux as well. Not only for MAC. We just dropped the non-brilliant idea of comparing imaging results with reference images in PNG format. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the difference is not related to OpenCV at all and is the behavior of function "std::fpclassify", where I am checking to see if the slope of a line is "NaN".  I am comparing the result to "1024" to see if it is a valid normal number, which is the enum "FP_NORMAL".  However, when compiled in linux, "FP_NORMAL" is equal to 4 instead of 1024!  Problem resolved.

Comment: Oh well if you found the solution than my answer is useless... I was writing it while you posted yours... I hope you can find it interesting anyway.

Comment: No, it is helpful and was on the right track.  In the end it was the platform dependent handling of floating points.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the few informations you gave us i can tell you that OpenCV algorithms and functions are platform independend. The only things mentioned on OpenCV docuemntations are:

---

Portability, External Dependencies

Formally, the code must comply with the C++ 98 standard. It's not recommended yet to use C++ 11 or TR1 extensions at the implementation level and it's forbidden to use it in the external headers.
One should get rid of compiler-dependent or platform-dependent constructions and system calls, such as:

- Compiler pragma's
- Specific keywords, e.g. __stdcall, __inline, __int64 (or long long). Use CV_INLINE (or simple inline in C++ code), CV_STDCALL (try to avoid it if possible), int64, respectively, instead.
- Compiler extensions, e.g. special macros for min and max, overloaded macros etc.
- Inline assembly
- Unix or Win32-specific calls, e.g. bcopy, readdir, CreateFile, WaitForSingleObject etc.
- Concrete data sizes instead of sizeof's (sizeof(int) rather than 4), byte order ( *(int*)"\x1\x2\x3\x4" is 0x01020304 or 0x04030201 or what?), simple char instead of signed char or unsigned char anywhere except for text strings. Use short forms uchar for unsigned char and schar for signed char. Use preprocessor directives for surrounding non-portable pieces of code.

source: [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Coding_Style_Guide)

---

Try and see if something in your code is platform dependent.
In my opinion (but it is just a feeling), probably it has something to do with representation of numbers in OpenCV Mats. Try and see if something is dependent on platform int size or float size...

That's all I can think of...